# Instantiate multiple Spring beans based on different property values

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

Consider a Spring component like:

```
@Component
public class Calculator {
  @Value("${rate:1.0}")
  private Double rate;

  ...
}
```

In a test, I'd like to instantiate three beans of this class based on the settings for property `rate`:

1. No value set (test: Calculator should use default value 1.0)
2. Positive value set (test: Calculator should work normally)
3. Negative value set (test: Calculator should throw an Exception)

It's easy to achieve this by writing three `@SpringBootTest`s, each with its own `@TestPropertySource`.

However, the result is rather ugly (the real production code is more complex than the simple example here).

Is there a way to instantiate three instances of the `@Component`, each based on a given `@TestPropertySource`?

I tried doing this in a `@Configuration` class; something like:

```
@Configuration
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"rate=2.0"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Calculator.class})
class PositiveRateCalculatorConfig {
  
  @Autowired
  private Calculator calc;

  @Bean
  Calculator positiveRateCalculator() {
      return calc;  
  }
}
```

But I didn't manage to auto-wire Calculator into the config class in such a way that `@TestPropertySource` takes effect.

Comment: The test scenarios you mentioned is default behaviour of Spring. Why you want to test already tested piece?

Comment: Do you need multiple  `Calculator`-beans in production?

Comment: @DirkDeyne One `Calculator` bean per environment (each environment has its own `rate` setting).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only **one** `Calculator`-bean in production and you want to test multiple configuration scenarios.

This is an excellent example of why the usage of `@Autowired` and `@Value` on fields is a bad practice. It kills tests..

Use `@Value` in a constructor

```java
@Component
public class Calculator {

  private final Double rate;

  Caluclator (@Value("${rate:1.0}") Double rate){
  
  }

  ...
}
```

Now **unit tests** are easy

```
public class CalulatorTest {
  
  @Test
  void positiveRate(){
    Calculator calculator = new Calulator(3d);
    ...
  }

  @Test
  void negativeRate(){
    Calculator calculator = new Calulator(-3d);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

*TIP: Avoid `@Autowire` in other beans*

Use constructor injection instead

```java
@Service
public class DemoService{

    private final Calculator calculator;

    public DemoService(Calculator calculator) {
        this.calculator = calculator;
    }
}
```

And test

```java
public DemoTest {

  DemoService service = new DemoService(new Calculator(2d));
  
  @Test
  void test(){
   ....
  } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk for the detailed answer. I also use constructor injection rather than field injection, but prefer not to go this way for two reasons: (1) The real code is much more complicated, and I want to avoid direct construction of objects. I rather prefer DI to take care of object construction. (2) If someone removes `@Value...` from the code, no test fails. That's an aspect I want to test: Whether the property is actually read and set in the bean.

Comment: A junit test should test the functionality of the components, not whether a value is present in `application.properties`. That could be done in an integration test. In your tests you use `@TestPropertySource`, so you do not test loading `@Value("rate")`. If you want to force that a rate-value is provided then you should not provide a default value (in Calculator). Just saying... it's your code...